# Autopopulate inputtext box on value selected

Tags: visualforce

I have a vf page where there are two fields country and continent. I want when i will select country the continent textbox should autopopulate with the corresponding value. Please help

```
<apex:page >

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css"/>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    //Create a new variable j$ just to avoid any conflicts with other libraries which may be using $.
    var j$ = jQuery.noConflict();
    //Capture the list of countries in a Array.
    var countryArray = ['India', 'USA', 'China','FInland','Norway','Netherlands','England','Ukraine','Russia','Japan','Korea','Burma','Srilanka','Iran','Iceland','Canada','Rome','Australia','Armenia','Albania','Afghanisthan'];
    var continents = ['ASIA','AFRICA','EUROPE','N.AMERICA','S.AMERICA'];
    //on Document ready
    j$(document).ready(function(){
        j$("#countryautocomplete").autocomplete({
        source : countryArray
        });
    });
    </script>
    <apex:form >
    <b>Enter Country: </b><input type="text" id="countryautocomplete"/> <b/>
    <b>Autopopulate Continent: </b><input type="text" id="countryautocomplete1"/>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>

Modified New One: - 
    <apex:page >

      <script src="{!URLFOR($Resource.jqueryauto, 'jquery-1.8.2.min.js')}" type="text/javascript"></script>
      <script src="{!URLFOR($Resource.jqueryauto, 'chosen.jquery.min.js')}" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{!URLFOR($Resource.jqueryauto, 'chosen.css')}" />
    </head>
    <body>
    <div style="width:500px;margin:0 auto;">
    <form action="" method="post">
        <div>
            <label class="control-label"> Countries </label>
          <div>
           <select data-placeholder="" name="program[]" class="chzn-select" multiple="multiple" tabindex="6" style="width:500px"> 
                <option value="India">INDIA</option>  
                <option value="China">CHINA</option>    
                <option value="FinLand">FINLAND</option>  
                <option value="USA">USA</option> 
                <option value="Srilanka">SRILANKA</option>
                <option value="Malasia">MALASIA</option>    
           </select>
            </div> <br/>
       <input type="text"/>
        </div>

         </form>
      </div>   

       <script>$(".chzn-select").chosen(); $(".chzn-select-deselect").chosen({allow_single_deselect:true});</script>
    </body>
    </html>
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Solution Updated

One quick solution is to make the continent array of same length with country array and populate continents name accordingly. Then display the continent name with the same array index. I have updated your code and it is working.

Not a great solution but it will work for you now..

```
<apex:page showHeader="true" sidebar="true">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css"/>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        //Create a new variable j$ just to avoid any conflicts with other libraries which may be using $.
        var j$ = jQuery.noConflict();
        //Capture the list of countries in a Array.
        var countryArray = ['India', 'USA', 'China','FInland','Norway','Netherlands','England','Ukraine','Russia','Japan','Korea','Burma','Srilanka','Iran','Iceland','Canada','Rome','Australia','Armenia','Albania','Afghanisthan'];
        var continents = ['ASIA', 'N.AMERICA', 'ASIA','EUROPE','EUROPE','EUROPE','EUROPE','EUROPE','ASIA','ASIA','ASIA','ASIA','ASIA','ASIA','EUROPE','N.AMERICA','EUROPE','AUSTRALIA','EUROPE','EUROPE','ASIA'];
        //on Document ready
        j$(document).ready(function(){
            j$("#countryautocomplete").autocomplete({
                source : countryArray,
                select: function( event, ui ) {
                    var arrIndex = countryArray.indexOf(ui.item.label);
                    j$("#countryautocomplete1").val(continents[arrIndex]);
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
    <apex:form>
        <b>Enter Country: </b><input type="text" id="countryautocomplete"/> <b/>
        <b>Autopopulate Continent: </b><input type="text" id="countryautocomplete1"/>
    </apex:form>    
</apex:page>
```

**Updated Solution**

This below code is for multi-select input field. For multi-select input field jQuery Plugin [Chosen](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/) is used.Based on the selection the continent textbox is autopopulated.

```
<apex:page >
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.4.2/chosen.jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.4.2/chosen.css"></link>
  <div style="width:500px;margin:0 auto;">
  <form action="" method="post">
    <div>
        <label class="control-label">Enter Country: </label>
      <div>
       <select data-placeholder="" name="program[]" class="chzn-select" multiple="multiple" tabindex="6" style="width:500px"> 
            <option value="India">INDIA</option>  
            <option value="China">CHINA</option>    
            <option value="FInland">FINLAND</option>  
            <option value="USA">USA</option> 
            <option value="Srilanka">SRILANKA</option>
            <option value="Malasia">MALASIA</option>    
       </select>
       </div> <br/>
       <b>Autopopulate Continent: </b>
       <input type="text" size="40" id="continentsText"/>
    </div>
    </form>
  </div>   
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var countryArray = ['India', 'USA', 'China','FInland','Norway','Netherlands','England','Ukraine','Russia','Japan','Korea','Burma','Srilanka','Iran','Iceland','Canada','Rome','Australia','Armenia','Albania','Afghanisthan'];
    var continents = ['ASIA', 'N.AMERICA', 'ASIA','EUROPE','EUROPE','EUROPE','EUROPE','EUROPE','ASIA','ASIA','ASIA','ASIA','ASIA','ASIA','EUROPE','N.AMERICA','EUROPE','AUSTRALIA','EUROPE','EUROPE','ASIA'];
    $(".chzn-select").chosen().change(function() {  
        var hexvalues = [];
        var labelvalues = [];
        var continentsFieldText = "";
        var continentName;
        $('.chzn-select :selected').each(function(i, selectedElement) {
            continentName = continents[countryArray.indexOf($(selectedElement).val())];
            if(continentsFieldText.indexOf(continentName)<0){
                continentsFieldText = continentsFieldText + ";"+continentName;
            }

        });
        //Remove the first semicolon and add to the Continent textbox
        $("#continentsText").val(continentsFieldText.substr(1));
    });         
  </script>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Saroj. That worked great. Can i make country as a multiselect. And when i will choose India , China, the common among them i.e Asia should autopopulate.

Comment: Which plugin are you using for multiselect? I can give it a try.

Comment: Also what will happen if I choose India and USA?

Comment: For multiselect i hvnt used yet. If India and USA is selected then continent should display as ASIA;N.AMERICA. Only if continent are common it should display one time not two times. Can u please help..

Comment: Hi Saroj.. I have tried using multiselect using jquery. But i don't how to autopopulate textbox with continents..

Comment: Can you post your multi select code, I am having some conflicts with plugins.

Comment: I downloaded the plugin from "http://www.crackerworld.in/2013/10/multiple-drop-down-select-box.html" site...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/28858/discussion-between-saroj-bera-and-sid).